# What's the best way to detect screen width and height on a Windows Store Application?

Tags: windows-store

I'm trying to detect the screen (not the Window) Width and Height.

I know that people use Window.Current.Bounds, but that gives me the Window size, not the screen.

I found this article (http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/tomershamam/2012/07/24/get-screen-resolution-in-windows-8-metro-style-application/) from Israel's Blogging Community. But it uses C++, is there any other way?

Answer (score 0):

you can use the `SystemInformation.PrimaryMonitorSize` you can find it into : `System.Windows.Forms` 
if you work into c#.

See the doc here : [http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.windows.forms.systeminformation.primarymonitorsize(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.windows.forms.systeminformation.primarymonitorsize%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)